# How to Color DataGridView while a large code is runing?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm building a data export app using C#.net(not wpf). And I have a data grid with 7 rows which contain export data. I have wrote a code to color each data row when a export is finished. Its a bit of a big code i got for the exporting part.

So it takes 30 sec to finish one export. The problem is When a export finished  for one row that particular row doesn't change the color until all 7 of them finished. Application kind a like not responding. When all 7 rows completed all rows change their colors as expected. Why is it not happening for each row when the code is runing. Any help would be appreciate.(im sure nothing wrong with the code)

Comment: Since we can see any code we can only guess. Try to ad d a DGV.Refresh() after coloring a row!

Comment: Maybe you need a Background worker

Comment: Ya it was refresh that i missed. thax